# Error in adding dynamic validation rules using jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using **jQuery validator plugin** in a html form.

*Client Side Scripting*: **Java Script/jQuery**

*Server Side Scripting*: **PHP**

I'll explain the form first. My form contains:

**a)** A textfield that accepts only email id

**b)** A textarea to add comments.

**c)** A textfield to enter user's name

**d)** A textfield to enter mobile number (accepts only number)

**a)** and **b)** are permanent residents of my form. No matter what happens, they remain in form forever. They are like the family guys.

**c)** and **d)** are temporary. Their existence depends on **a)**. That is email id.

If the email id entered by the user does not contain in database, **c)** and **d)** comes in action. User will have to enter their username and mobile number and all the four fields need to be validated. If not, only the first two fields will be validated. I kinda messed things here.

And I'm validating all these fields using jQuery validator plugin from client side. There's a validation in server-side also. I'm not goin' into that here. Let's skip it for the time being.

To check email exist, I use plugin's remote feature. I tried two methods to turn on/off validation rules for c) and d) and both of 'em failed. :)

```
<form role="form" id="product_description_form" name="product_description_form" method="POST" action="place_order_action.php" >
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 title bg-black">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="email_id" name="email_id"  class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea type="text" id="product_description" name="product_description"  class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="fullname_div" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
            <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name">
        </div>

        <div id="mobilenum_div" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
            <input type="text" id="mob_num" name="mob_num"  class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="finish" value="CONFIRM NOW" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Initially I keep mobile number and name div's hidden. If email id does not match, I'll show 'em to the user. And at that time, name and mobile field's type will be changed to text from hidden. Else, the type remains hidden. I somewhere heard hidden fields don't get validated. That's why I took this route.

I thought of making a fiddle at first. But I'm working with remote, so it's kinda out of picture, you know. Maybe.

Here's ***First Method*** I tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#product_description_form').validate({
        rules: {
            email_id: {
                email: true,
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "checkemail_exist.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {
                        email_id: function() {
                            return $("#email_id").val();
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(dataa) {
                        var condition = dataa.trim();

                        //Invalid Data              
                        if (condition == "2") 
                        {
                            remove_validation();          
                            document.getElementById('email_id').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').value = '';
                            alert('Please enter a valid email id.');
                        }
                        //Existing User
                        else if (condition == "1") 
                        {
                            remove_validation();           
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').type = 'hidden';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').type = 'hidden';
                            alert('We will contact you.');
                        }
                        //New User
                        else if (condition == "3") 
                        {
                            add_validation();
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').type = 'text';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').type = 'text';
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'block';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'block';
                            alert('New User.');
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            remove_validation();
                            document.getElementById('email_id').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').value = '';
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            product_description: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            }

        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element.text('').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });

function add_validation()
{
    $("#full_name").rules("add", "required");
    $("#mob_num").rules("add", {number: true, required:true, minlength: 10, maxlength:12 });
}

function remove_validation()
{
    $("#full_name").rules("remove", "required");
    $("#mob_num").rules("remove", {number: true, required:true, minlength: 10, maxlength:12 });     
}

});
```

Guess what? It didn't work. I know, I know I'm mixing jQuery and JavaScript. But this is just a demo.
Anyway, after the successful failure of my first method, I tried using depends property of the plugin. There's always a Plan B. :D

Here's ***Second Method*** I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Function to validate

    $('#product_description_form').validate({
        rules: {
            email_id: {
                email: true,
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "checkemail_exist.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: {
                        email_id: function() {
                            return $("#email_id").val();
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(dataa) {
                        var condition = dataa.trim();

                        //Invalid Data              
                        if (condition == "2") 
                        {
                            document.getElementById('email_id').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').value = '';
                            alert('Please enter a valid email id.');
                        }
                        //Existing User
                        else if (condition == "1") 
                        {
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').type = 'hidden';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').type = 'hidden';
                            alert('We will contact you.');
                        }
                        //New User
                        else if (condition == "3")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').type = 'text';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').type = 'text';
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'block';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'block';
                            alert('New User.');
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            document.getElementById('email_id').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('mobilenum_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('fullname_div').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('mob_num').value = '';
                            document.getElementById('full_name').value = '';
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            product_description: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            full_name: 
            {
                required: 
                {
                    depends: function(element) 
                    {
                        if (condition == "3") 
                        {
                            return true;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            mob_num: 
            {
                required:
                {
                    depends: function(element) 
                    {
                        if (condition == "3") 
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                },
                number: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 12
            }

        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element.text('').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });

});
```

Sometimes Plan B also fails. So we find a Plan C. This is it.
Where all did I make mistake? Gracias.

remote method works fine. I even get response from checkemail_exist.php page and if-else conditions inside success is checked too. But validation rules are not being added and removed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching it in the wrong way, you can just the hide the elements then the validation rules will not be applied.

So you can set the validation rules, then can use a change event handler which can set the display of these elements based on whether the email exists or not.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#product_description_form').validate({
    rules: {
      email_id: {
        email: true,
        required: true,
      },
      product_description: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10
      },
      full_name: {
        required: true
      },
      mob_num: {
        number: true,
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 12
      }
    }
  });

  $('#email_id').change(function() {
    //based on the value set the display state of those fields
    //as a temp implementation we will just toggle the display
    //using timeout to simulate a async ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#mobilenum_div, #fullname_div').toggle();
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="product_description_form" name="product_description_form" method="POST" action="place_order_action.php">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 title bg-black">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="email_id" name="email_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea type="text" id="product_description" name="product_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="fullname_div" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name">
    </div>

    <div id="mobilenum_div" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" id="mob_num" name="mob_num" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="finish" value="CONFIRM NOW" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```